How to represent unitary evolution in Python?
How to represent $U(t)$ (a unitary operator) in a code? Is there any package available for that in Python?

This depends a bit on what you want to use the operator for. If you want to build a quantum circuit from your unitary, Qiskit is a good Python package for designing and running quantum circuits -- there are lots of good introductory videos on YouTube.
To represent a general unitary operator and build a circuit which implements that unitary, you can write your unitary as a matrix (a list of lists) and use it to create a UnitaryGate object, which you can in turn feed into a QuantumCircuit:
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit.library import UnitaryGate

# Write unitary as a matrix:
matrix = [[0, 0, 0, 1],
          [0, 0, 1, 0],
          [1, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 1, 0, 0]]

# Convert to UnitaryGate object
gate = UnitaryGate(matrix)

# Create quantum circuit implementing that gate
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.append(gate, [0, 1])
circuit.draw()

outputs a picture of the quantum circuit with your unitary attached:
     ┌──────────┐
q_0: ┤0         ├
     │  Unitary │
q_1: ┤1         ├
     └──────────┘

If you want to implement a time-dependent unitary of the form $U(t) = \text{exp}(-itH)$, you could also use the HamiltonianGate object.

I'd also highly recommend the qutip package for implementing unitaries, which is more tailored towards analog quantum computing than Qiskit.
